# C program won't use printf after scanf

Tags: c, compiler-errors, printf, scanf

I am new to C and am writing a very simple C program which just provides a input and repeats it back to you. The code shows the first print f which is a $ and lets you input something but will not print the text back to you. Here is the code:

```
char input[50];
    printf("$");
    scanf("%s\n", input);
    printf("\n %s", input);
```

I thought it might have been a compile issue but nothing changes. I use make token which is the name of the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the "\n" in the `scanf()` format string.  The trailing "\n" instructs `scanf()` to match any number of white space characters and it will only know when it's done when encountering a non-white space character.  Meanwhile you expect it to return after reading the first "\n".  Consider using `fgets()` instead.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char input[50];
    printf("$");
    scanf("%s", input);
    printf("\n %s", input);
}
```

and example session:

```
$abc

 abc
```